# Django - User full name as unicode

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I have many Models linked to `User` and I'd like my templates to always display his full_name if available. Is there a way to change the default `User` `__unicode__()` ? Or is there another way to do it ?

I have a profile model registered where I can define the `__unicode__()`, should I link all my models to it ? Seems not a good idea to me.

---

Imagine I need to display the form for this object

```
class UserBagde
    user = model.ForeignKey(User)
    badge = models.ForeignKey(Bagde)
```

I will have to select box with `__unicodes__` of each object, won't I ?
How can I have full names in the user's one ?

Comment: Also remember first_name and last_name are optional fields in User. so some elements of your select box could have no text if you go with this approach!

Comment: That's why I said "if available" meaning fallback to default if not

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.full_name = property(lambda u: u"%s %s" % (u.first_name, u.last_name))
```

## EDIT

Apparently what you want already exists..

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_full_name

## ALSO

if its imperative that the unicode function be replaced:

```
def user_new_unicode(self):
    return self.get_full_name()

# Replace the __unicode__ method in the User class with out new implementation
User.__unicode__ = user_new_unicode 

# or maybe even
User.__unicode__ = User.get_full_name()
```

## Fallback if name fields are empty

```
def user_new_unicode(self):
    return self.username if self.get_full_name() == "" else self.get_full_name()

# Replace the __unicode__ method in the User class with out new implementation
User.__unicode__ = user_new_unicode
```

Comment: That's more what I'm searching. Is there somewhere I can put this assignment in order to have it anywhere ?

Comment: put it in the models.py of ANY installed app, I generally have a membership app, that has my profile model, I would put this under that declaration, but that s more personal preference than anything.

Comment: I agree with the profile location, I'll that thanks. Actually it seems to work even when I don't import the profile model, I don't understand  how :) ...

Comment: you don't have to import any models, just by having the app in your installed apps is enough.

Comment: how to call this method from view?

Comment: you wouldn't probably call the unicode replacement functions directly: `full_name = str(request.user)` gets the unicode string representation of the currently logged in user OR `full_name = request.user.get_full_name()` OR `full_name = request.user.__unicode__()` it really kinda depends on what you are doing.

Comment: You may mean: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.get_full_name

Comment: @AntonioRomero This question/answer was for a much earlier version of Django. The answer above should work for all versions through Django 1.11.x LTS End of Life

Comment: You are right. But at the given (dev) link there is actually no information about the function `get_full_name`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a profile model [set up as Django suggests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users), you could define the full name on that model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...

@property
def full_name(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

then anywhere you have access to the `user` object you can easily do `user.get_profile.full_name`

Alternatively, if you only need the full name in the template you could write a [simple tag:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

```
@register.simple_tag
def fullname(user):
    return "%s %s" % (user.first_name, user.last_name)
```

Comment: That's what I'm already doing when I can access to the user object directly (as I said I already have a profile model) but for example in forms when I have to choose from a user in a list, I'll always have usernames displaied

Answer (score 1):

Just slam `get_full_name` to the `__unicode__` method like so

```
User.__unicode__ = User.get_full_name
```

Make sure you override it with the callable, not the result of the function. `User.get_full_name()` will fail with the open and close brackets.

Place on any included file and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I found there's a quick way to do this in Django 1.5. Check this:
[custom User models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/#customizing-the-user-model)

and I also notice,

```
User.__unicode__ = User.get_full_name()
```

which metions by Francis Yaconiello is not work on my side (Django 1.3). Will raise error like this:

```
TypeError: unbound method get_full_name() must be called with User instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```