# Django: Display first_name and last_name

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an app where a person can login, do stuff, and see their personal information like their first_name, last_name, email, username, etc. So far I have the application displaying their username and email, but not first_name or last_name.

If I go on the admin site and I look under "Users", it only displays the username and email of the user, but not the first_name or last_name. So that's most likely the problem, but I don't know how to get this information to "save."

Here's my "Student" model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

EDIT: I created a student admin with all that information. Here's what it looks like:

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    inlines = StudentInline
```

If I manually add the first and last name of the user, it works perfectly. But it's not adding them even after this change.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902262/django-user-full-name-as-unicode

Comment: Are you using the built-in `User` model?

Comment: I just edited my original post to include my Student model

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking into the Admin Site section for this and the section known as list_display.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/

How I done this in a recent app was the list_display section to display only area of the app I wanted to see in the dropdown.

```
@admin.register(Surah)
class SurahAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Note: Admin Interface to maintain Surah Information
    list_display  = [ '__str__', 'lk' ] # Show the List of every Surah
    list_filter   = [ 'nm' ]            # The Side box for filters
    search_fields = [ 'nm' ]            # A Search field
    ordering      = [ 'id' ]            # How you want to order it

    # Note: Additional Inline Information 
    inlines = [ AyahsInline ]          # Look to inline, mainly for One 
                                       # to many relationship
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show the Student model, You need to add them to your list_display in the admin.py file to show the screen like this.

But it seems like you are clicking on the User in the admin and not the student.

[image]